# Shoud I tell them why I'm turning down their job offer?

Tags: job-offer

Basically, I've had two interviews with a company. They seemed to have really liked me and really want me to be part of their team as a software dev. The problem is I'm currently a student, to join them I would have to drop out of school. After converting their salary numbers to $/h I realize my current part time job as a web dev pays slightly more.

If I stay in school, in January, I can do Coop with a different company that pays even higher which already got me a job offer. The interviewers and two senior engineers of the company which I've had the interview in were really nice to me during the interview and really wanted to rope me in so I feel like I might owe them an explanation for turning their offer down. Should I tell them all the reasons or should I just make it brief.

Comment: your part time pays more per hour or overall? Why did you do the interviews, were you contemplating dropping out or just seeing what it's like?

Comment: Welcome new user.  Keep it very brief.  You owe them nothing. Just state that you need to finish school first.

Comment: Most interviewers are interested in "being nice". They're likely not being nice as the job requires, rather than as an act of courtesy to you.

Comment: Your reasons only matter if a) there is anything they can do to change your mind and b) they want you enough to be willing to make those changes. You need to ask yourself, if they offered you more money or made some other changes, would it affect your decision. If the answer is no (or if the answer is "no unless they offered me a ridiculously large amount") then you're probably doing them a bigger favour by keeping the details sparse and saving them some time. If you make it sound like a "maybe" by giving reasons, you're encouraging them to spend time trying to win you over.

Comment: @Kilisi I only got the salary numbers after the second interview which was also when they made me an offer, I had a few days to think about it.

Answer (score 2):

I see two major different reasons:

- The first one is that you should stay in school so can get your degree. This degree can be very important during the first decade of your career (and even after). Except if the job offer is something that you cannot normally expect with your future degree, *the kind of opportunity that cannot be turned down*, you should finish your studies first.
  You can tell them this reason, it will sound logic, reasonable and professional for most people.
- The second one is about the salary. You can turn this problem into a negotiation: you should tell them your expectations as anybody would do while looking for a job.

If they keep their first offer, then nothing changes for you. If they can reconsider it, then that could be a good opportunity for you.